# How to sink roof

Tags: modeling

How can I extrude this middle part of the roof down so that I can start putting tiles on it? If I extrude + scale down it looks weird, same if I try extrude + move. I simply want it to become thinner, but not scale inwards on the sides.

[image]

Comment: you can't extrude down in that case, except with addons like Destructive Extrude, I don't know if it's available for 2.8: youtube.com/watch?v=beZau_wpR-U other than that, you you can do it the other way around, meaning you extrude up each side, etc…

Comment: The updated version is available on GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to *Inset the faces* with value of 0.
And at the same time add a negative depth.

Just like this. 
[image]

Or, if you want better control. Leave the depth at 0 as well, and just use the *Move Tool* to move the top faces where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> *> Extrude along Normals*. Not perfect, but it will probably do the job in this case with minimum geometry and a bit of cleanup afterwards.

Alternatively, you could separate the faces using <kbd>P</kbd> to create a new object, which you will be able to move freely. Downside is that you would have to adjust the polygons and create a new face for each side, of course.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start
2. Moved to horizontal
3. Top and side moved down and right by 0.3 respectively
4. Extruded by 0.3
5. Step 4 rotated 90 deg Y and sheared, rotated back.
   [image]